# spring @autowired - without using hardcoded xml file

Tags: spring, autowired

I am trying implement a sample project with struts2 and spring. I have followed [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/) example and it worked fine. But in every action I need hardcode spring.xml configuration file like below. How can i get rid of the following statement?

```
ApplicationContext context =
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {“SpringBeans.xml”});

Customer cust = (Customer)context.getBean(“CustomerBean”);
System.out.println(cust);
```

I want to write something like below

```
@Autowired
Customer customer;
```

does the above declaration works?if yes how spring will look for xml configuration file? will spring check that in classpath?

Comment: You need to provide more context for this. How are you running your app? How are you bootstrapping the spring container? Can you show us your application-context (SpringBeans.xml)?

Comment: here is the example i am talking about...i have mentioned the link in description...http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

Answer (score 1):

As @engineer-dollery alludes, there should only be one bootstrap for the Spring `ApplicationContext`. You can instantiate it yourself (as in your example), but the typical way of doing this for a servlet-based web app is by adding something like the following in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:SpringBeans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then, if you want to use autowiring, you can define the following in your `SpringBeans.xml` file:

```
...
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
...
<context:component-scan base-package="package.containing.your.beans" />
```

And make sure to annotate the classes that have `@Autowired` fields with an appropriate stereotype, like `@Component` or `@Service` (or `@Controller` to use Spring MVC instead of Struts).

Note, however, that dependencies can only be injected via autowiring if they themselves are either:

1. defined as beans in your xml config or
2. annotated with a stereotype and in a package that you have told Spring to scan for components

Otherwise, take a look at these for tutorials/examples of integrating Spring and Struts:

- http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html
- http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-integration-example/
- http://www.slideshare.net/Syed_Shahul/struts-2-and-spring-frameworks-together